# Finding number of pages using Python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to extract the total page number (11 in this case) from a steam page. I believe that the following code should work (return 11), but it is returning an empty list. Like if it is not finding `paged_items_paging_pagelink` class.

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get('http://store.steampowered.com/tags/en-us/RPG/')
c = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(c, 'html.parser')


total_pages = soup.find_all("span",{"class":"paged_items_paging_pagelink"})[-1].text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the page source, the content you want is not available. It means that it is generated dynamically through Javascript.

The page numbers are located inside the `<span id="NewReleases_links">` tag, but in the page source the HTML shows only this:

```
<span id="NewReleases_links"></span>
```

Easiest way to handle this is using [Selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium).

But, if you look at the page source, the text `Showing 1-20 of 213 results`
 is available. So, you can scrape this and calculate the number of pages.

Required HTML:

```
<div class="paged_items_paging_summary ellipsis">
    Showing 
    <span id="NewReleases_start">1</span>
    -
    <span id="NewReleases_end">20</span> 
    of 
    <span id="NewReleases_total">213</span> 
    results         
</div>
```

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('http://store.steampowered.com/tags/en-us/RPG/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

def get_pages_no(soup):
    total_items = int(soup.find('span', id='NewReleases_total').text)
    items_per_page = int(soup.find('span', id='NewReleases_end').text)
    return round(total_items/items_per_page)

print(get_pages_no(soup))
# prints 11
```

(Note: I still recommend the use of Selenium, as most of the content from this site is dynamically generated. It'll be a pain to scrape all the data like this.)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative faster way without using `BeautifulSoup`:

```
import requests

url = "http://store.steampowered.com/contenthub/querypaginated/tags/NewReleases/render/?query=&start=20&count=20&cc=US&l=english&no_violence=0&no_sex=0&v=4&tag=RPG" # This returns your query in json format
r = requests.get(url)

print(round(r.json()['total_count'] / 20)) # total_count = number of records, 20 = number of pages shown
```

> 11

Comment: You could also use the [builtin JSON decoder](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content). No need to use another module. +1 for finding a better solution.