# How can i take the pagecount number with BeatifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a code like this;

```
while True:
baslik = input('Başlık:')
if baslik == 'q':
    break
r = requests.get(site + baslik , headers=headers)    
if r.status_code != 200:
    print('I dont find!')
else:
    soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')
    s = soup.find(id="topic").find_all("div")        
    sz = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "pager"})        
    print(sz)
    print(type(sz))
```

and this is the result of it;

```
div class="pager" data-currentpage="1" data-pagecount="39"></div, div class="pager" data-currentpage="1" data-pagecount="39">/div
```

How can i take the page-count number which is 39 for i am using for loop to **scrape** all data on web side.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding number of pages using Python BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49035188/finding-number-of-pages-using-python-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `sz = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "pager"})` gets the result as `<div class="pager" data-currentpage="1" data-pagecount="39"></div><div class="pager" data-currentpage="1" data-pagecount="39"></div>`, I suggest replace `find_all()` with `find()` first.

Please try the following code and let me know the result if you want.

```
paper = soup.find('div', {'class', 'pager'})
pagecount = paper.get('data-pagecount')
print(pagecount)
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the page-count number, you will have to use the Selenium Module. Here is a link with sample code to help you:

[Finding number of pages using Python BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49035188/finding-number-of-pages-using-python-beautifulsoup)

Hope this helps!