# My while loop to scrape all pages in the website is not working

Tags: python, web-scraping

Here is the website I am trying to scrape: https://books.toscrape.com/

Below are my functions. The scrape_all_pages() is not working. Is there a better way to get the page number from the website directly so I can use the range function instead?

I did checkout [Finding number of pages using Python BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49035188/finding-number-of-pages-using-python-beautifulsoup)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_soup(url):
    """Takes a URL and returns a BeautifulSoup() instance representing the HTML of the page."""

    response = requests.get(url)
    html = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

    return soup

def scrape_page(num):
    """Takes a page and returns a list of links to the book that are on the page."""
    
    BASE_URL = 'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/'    
    PAGE_URL = BASE_URL + str('page-')
    
    book_url = []

    soup = get_soup(PAGE_URL + str(num)+ '.html')
    for x in soup.findAll("article", class_ = "product_pod"):
        url = x.div.a.get('href')
        link = BASE_URL + url
        if x not in book_url:
            book_url.append(link)
        
    return book_url

def scrape_all_pages():
    """Scrapes all pages, returning a list of book links."""
    
    page_num = 0
    all_urls = []    

    while True:
        url = scrape_page(page_num)
        if not url:
            break
        all_urls += url
        page_num += 1

    return all_urls
```

Answer (score 0):

It do not need `range()` in most cases. Would recommend to change strategy and take a look if there is a link to next page available or not:

```
if soup.select_one('li.next a[href]'):
    nextPage = BASE_URL + soup.select_one('li.next a[href]')['href']
else:
    nextPage = None
```

or from `python`3.8 and later:

```
nextPage = BASE_URL + a['href'] if(a := soup.select_one('li.next a[href]')) else None
```

###### Example

**Note** *Starts from https://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-45.html to limit for demo. You could simply change it to get https://books.toscrape.com/ getting all pages scraped*

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_soup(url):
    """Takes a URL and returns a BeautifulSoup() instance representing the HTML of the page."""

    response = requests.get(url)
    html = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

    return soup

def scrape_page(url):
    """Takes a page and append link of the books that are on the page to global list"""
    BASE_URL = 'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/'

    soup = get_soup(url)
    for x in soup.find_all("article", class_ = "product_pod"):
        url = x.div.a.get('href')
        link = BASE_URL + url
        if x not in book_url:
            book_url.append(link)
    if soup.select_one('li.next a[href]'):
        nextPage = BASE_URL + soup.select_one('li.next a[href]')['href']
    else:
        nextPage = None

    return nextPage

def scrape_all_pages(url):
    """Scrapes all pages, returning a list of book links."""
    while True:
        if url:
            print(url)
            url = scrape_page(url)
        else:
            break
    return book_url

book_url = []

scrape_all_pages('https://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-45.html')
```

###### Output

```
['http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/annie-on-my-mind_120/index.html',
 'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/and-then-there-were-none_119/index.html',
 'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/a-walk-in-the-woods-rediscovering-america-on-the-appalachian-trail_118/index.html',
 'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/a-visit-from-the-goon-squad_117/index.html',
 'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/a-storm-of-swords-a-song-of-ice-and-fire-3_116/index.html',
 'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/a-heartbreaking-work-of-staggering-genius_115/index.html',
 'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/8-keys-to-mental-health-through-exercise_114/index.html',
 'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/girlboss_113/index.html',
 'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/the-suffragettes-little-black-classics-96_112/index.html',
 'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/the-sense-of-an-ending_111/index.html',
 'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/the-sandman-vol-2-the-dolls-house-the-sandman-volumes-2_110/index.html',
 'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/the-course-of-love_109/index.html',
 'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/sugar-rush-offensive-line-2_108/index.html',
 'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/saga-volume-2-saga-collected-editions-2_107/index.html',
 'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/run-spot-run-the-ethics-of-keeping-pets_106/index.html',...]
```